# I would like to pass my autocompletetexxtview text to IntentService class

Tags: android, intentservice

I have a class that extends IntentService based on [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html).
I would appreciate any help.

```
//This is the method in my main activity that throws exception. I wanted this to call the IntentService by passing the autocompletetextview text within the Intent.The content is Lat and Lon coordinate I would like to reverse geocode in the IntentService Handler.


protected void startIntentService(String passedst) {
        try{
            if (passedst != null){
        //acrilocation = (AutoCompleteTextView)    findViewById(R.id.actvriderlocation);
        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
        myintent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
        myintent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA,  Location.convert(passedst));
        startService(myintent);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "There is a problem with your arguments");
        }
    }
```

This is logcat piece, this is in response to the request I got to provide the full logcat details

```
02-17 23:38:09.883: D/AbsListView(16456): onDetachedFromWindow
02-17 23:38:09.933: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(16456): 
Parent view is not a TextView
02-17 23:38:09.943: I/Google Maps Android API(16456): Google Play         services package version: 
6599036
02-17 23:38:09.973: D/AbsListView(16456): Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-17 23:38:10.013: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16456): 
showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-17 23:38:10.043: E/ViewRootImpl(16456): sendUserActionEvent()      mView    == null
02-17 23:38:10.543: 
D/dalvikvm(16456): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14454K, 50% free 16195K/32228K,       paused 81ms, total 81ms
02-17 23:38:12.013: W/System.err(16456): 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: coordinate=46.6667777, 122.5556666
```

Comment: When I run it in a device, I get the error "There is a problem with your arguments" in the Logcat.

Comment: please print the actual logcat instead of your log i.e e.printStacktrace()

Comment: print your stacktrace

Comment: The idea is to retrieve the longitude and latitude from the textbox and pass them to the handler and get them converted to an address and display the address in the textbox like edittext.setText(theaddress).

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown: Debug and see what is content of `passedst`? This string should be in  one of the formats described by FORMAT_DEGREES, FORMAT_MINUTES, or FORMAT_SECONDS.

Answer (score 0):

Since an exception is thrown, I think the problem is likely the string you are passing.
Here the Location.convert from the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#convert(java.lang.String)).

> Converts a String in one of the formats described by FORMAT_DEGREES,
> FORMAT_MINUTES, or FORMAT_SECONDS into a double.
>
> Throws NullPointerException   if coordinate is null
> IllegalArgumentException  if the coordinate is not in one of the valid
> formats.

You may want to check the string you are passing.

Comment: I changed my intent and my Intentservice is getting the intent and processes it and returns the address after reverse geocoding the latitude and longitude. But the third line throws nullpointerexception when sending the result back to the activity as such private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
        
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
   mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
    }